# vbscript bad file name when using variable from text file

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want to create a vbscript program that reads a .ini file to get parameters and use it.

My parameter file contains several parameters:

propertyfile.ini

```
"C:\PROGRA~1\narrowcast\scripts\transferStatusLog.txt"
..other parameters
..more parameters
```

my vbscript will read the file and use it

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objPropertyFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\PROGRA~1\scripts\propertyfile.ini", 1)
Do Until objPropertyFile.AtEndOfStream
    myfile = objPropertyFile.ReadLine
    ... other parameters for use on other fso object
Loop

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogProgram = objFSO.CreateTextFile(myfile)
```

Im having an error bad file name or number. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading in the quotes - vbscript is not liking that. You'll need to strip them off.
Here's a quick and dirty replacement. Don't forget to add a check to see if it exists - otherwise if it doesn't you'll probably get a path not found error.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objPropertyFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\PROGRA~1\scripts\propertyfile.ini", 1)
Do Until objPropertyFile.AtEndOfStream
    myfile = replace (objPropertyFile.ReadLine,"""","")
Loop

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogProgram = objFSO.CreateTextFile(myfile)
```

**What are we doing here?**

We are simply telling vbscript to replace the double quote character with nothing (we had to "escape it, by double quoting, etc):

```
myfile = replace (objPropertyFile.ReadLine,"""","")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, does not display the error anymore, but it does not create the file though

Comment: I solved the problem by giving full control permission to a specific folder. but your answer helped a lot. thanks @Damien